# Disable password on linux user with command

Tags: linux, security, password, shadow

Based on [`/etc/shadow(5)` documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) on the second (password) field:

> #### encrypted password
>
> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result
> of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a
> unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other
> means).

My question is whether there is a linux command to disable the user password,i.e. set a "*" or a "!" on password field.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking for `passwd -l user`.

From `man passwd`:

> Options:
>
> [...]
>
> -l, --lock                    lock the password of the named account. This option disables a
>              password by changing it to a value which matches no possible
>              encrypted value (it adds a '!' at the beginning of the password).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply disable password by just deleting it.
You must have sudo privilege!
use command:

```
sudo passwd -d <username>
```

Here is an coloum from man passwd:

> -d,    --delete   Delete a user's password (make it empty). This is a quick way to disable a password for an account. It will set the named account passwordless.

Comment: As described, this will set an *empty password*! This is different from **locking** the account, as it will NOT prevent login by password.

Comment: `sudo passwd -dl <username>` will remove password and disable