# How to remove login password and username in debian 11?

Tags: linux, debian

I'm having an application where I'm using debug port as the main communication port where after booting user is trying to enter commands but because of the login password, we are not able to access debug port directly.

How we can disable the login password in Debian 11?

Comment: I think it depends on  your displaymanager. If you habe one `cat  /etc/X11/default-display-manager`

Comment: @nobody I dont have any display manager. I'm running minimal debian 11.6 on imx6ull

Comment: Not not tested nowadays My serverhardware is gone. Create file /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf; with content.`[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I $TERM
Type=idle
`

Comment: whenever i try to save the file it is showing
/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing @nobody

Comment: Did you create the folder before? `mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/` ?

Comment: @nobody actually I found that issue. Because of the rsyslogd daemon, my sd card has become full and I don't have any space to save the file. I will try to make space then I will check once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable password on linux user with command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558590/disable-password-on-linux-user-with-command)